# No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'IEnumerable`1' from content with media type 'text/html in asp.net mvc webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC web application using Web API and ASP.NET MVC together. I get this error:

> No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'IEnumerable`1' from content with media type 'text/html

studentController (mvcproject)

```
namespace Mvcproj.Controllers
{
   public class studentController : Controller
   {
        public static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        // GET: Employes
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1747/api");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            IEnumerable<studmodel> emplist;
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("studen").Result;
            Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            emplist = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<studmodel>>().Result;          //here get an error
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return View(emplist);
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Mvcproj.Models.studmodel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.studid)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.username)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.password)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.studid)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.username)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.password)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Output:

http://localhost:1785/studen/index

studentController (api project)

```
namespace WebsApi.Controllers
{
    public class studentController : ApiController
    {
        private studangEntities db = new studangEntities();

        // GET: api/studen
        public IQueryable<student> Getstudents()
        {
            return db.students;
        }

        // GET: api/studen/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(student))]
        public IHttpActionResult Getstudent(int id)
        {
            student student = db.students.Find(id);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(student);
        }
      }
}
```

Output:

http://localhost:1747/api/studen

```
<ArrayOfstudent xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebsApi.Models">
    <student>
        <password>admin@123</password>
        <studid>1017</studid>
        <username>admin</username>
    </student>
    <student>
        <password>devis</password>
        <studid>1025</studid>
        <username>devis</username>
    </student>
```

I also changed `application/xml` - but that's causing the same error.

When I'm debugging:

```
content  {System.Net.Http.StreamContent}

status code  System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound

requestmessage {Method: GET, RequestUri: 'http://localhost:1747/studen', Version: 1.1, Content: <null>, Headers:
{
Accept: text/json
}}
```

I'm referring to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters       but error not solved

how to solve this error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see here

```
requestmessage {Method: GET, RequestUri: 'http://localhost:1747/studen', Version: 1.1, Content: , Headers: { Accept: text/json }}
```

the request URI is `http://localhost:1747/studen` but you need `http://localhost:1747/api/studen`

Add `/` at the end of base URI

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1747/api/");
```